# D3.js Bilevel Partition - initial chart load zoomed on slice

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to know if there's a way to start a D3.js Bilevel Partition zoomed in on a slice, instead of on the default where all values are shown. Is this possible?

Bilevel Partition:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371

A possible solution is to write some code that automatically clicks one of the slices.

Another backup solution is to create separate charts instead - one with just the data in the zoomed slice and a separate button that loads the second chart.

Or instead there's an update button, where the zoomed in slices are the only data present at first, and by clicking that button the rest of the data are added. (How to implement this though?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo for *"A possible solution is to write some code that automatically clicks one of the slices."*

This will select the node you wish like this:

```
  path[0].every(function(p){
    var d = d3.select(p).data();
    //put the name of the node you wish to zoom on i have put "Arrays"
    if (d[0].name == "Arrays"){
      var k = d[0];
      zoomIn(k);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
```

Full working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hZIkaToanYERNDDfycYq?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This method works perfectly! Although it would be nice if there's a way to remove the animation at the beginning. The point is to hide the other slices to viewers and the transition gives this away.

Comment: Try this now http://plnkr.co/edit/hZIkaToanYERNDDfycYq?p=preview i am passing a third parameter fast which when true the delay will be 0.
 _if(fast ==true)       delay = 0;_ Line No:176-178. So on first Load i pass this value as true ..but never on other cases.